# Exporting private key from a certificate into. pem file on Mac

Tags: macos, ssl, certificate

tl;dr

1. Does a certificate contain both private key and public key?
2. If so, how can I export a private key to `.pem` from a certificate on Mac? When you export a certificate in KeyChain Access, it give you only one `.pem` file and it is not a private key.
3. If not, how can I get one? Because I clearly I have it somewhere in the computer that enables corporate services.

I only have a scattered ideas on how certificate works so pardon me for just laying out things I know and have.

I have a certificate issued by my company (I will call it Orange for reference).
Orange certificate is needed to make an API call.
From the example for the API call, I need to provide public key from Orange and private key.  Both of them are `.pem`.

I honestly don't know if Orange certificate in KeyChain Access is supposed to contain both public and private key but I assume so because a certificate works with two keys that work together and Certificate Export Wizard on Windows gives you option whether you want to export private key when you try to export a certificate.

The problem is when I export my Orange certificate from KeyChain Access, it gives no such option. I only get one `.pem` file (or `.cer` or `.p7b` depending on what format I chose) and it doesn't look like a private key.

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...many characters...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I can see Keys section in Keychain Access. But the certificate's name is not Orange..

[image]

Comment: A certificate does not contain both public and private keys, only the public key.

Comment: The terminology for all this is confusing; sometimes when people speak of a certificate, they mean just the certificate proper (which contains the public key, but not the private key), and sometimes they mean the certificate together with the corresponding private key. Look in the "My Certificates" section -- that shows certificates that you have the private key for. If it's not shown there, you don't have the private key (or at least, it's not in the keychain).

Comment: BTW, "PEM" just says how the data's formatted, not what data is there, so it's not specific enough. You probably want a [PKCS#12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12) (.p12) file containing cert + encrypted private key, in PEM format. Keychain Access can export in this format, if you find the cert + key in the "My Certificates" section. You can also export the cert and key separately if you want to.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you for all the knowledge. I don't have Orange certificate or key under "My Certificates" so guess it's the kind of certificate without private key.